# Unity, scaling is changing, but i do not wrote any code or change anything

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, camera, 2d, scale

I am making a small 2D game with a Youtube tutorial. Now I am trying to add floattext. When I show my text, the scale of my text goes from 1 to 540, thus text is as big as player cannot see it. An example image is below:

[as shown, the text is so big. Its scale is somehow 540.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eRxd.png)

I make UI's (Canvas's) render mode to "Screen Space - Camera", then drag the main camera to canvas. After I've selected the "UI scale mode" to "Scale With Size". My reference resolution is 1920*1080. The reference pixel per unit is 1.

If I drop text prefab to the scene, the text is showing with normal size. But if I call it with collapsing (When my character touches a chest, then text occurs) size of the text is huge.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FloatingTextManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject textContainer;
    public GameObject textPrefab;

    private List<FloatingText> floatingTexts = new List<FloatingText>();

    private void Update() {
        foreach (FloatingText txt in floatingTexts)
        {
            txt.UpdateFloationgText();
        }
    }

    public void Show(string msg, int fontSize, Color color, Vector3 position, Vector3 motion, float duration) {
        FloatingText floatingText = GetFloatingText();

        floatingText.txt.text = msg;
        floatingText.txt.fontSize = fontSize;
        floatingText.txt.color = color;
        floatingText.go.transform.position = position;
        floatingText.motion = motion;
        floatingText.duration = duration;

        floatingText.Show();

    }

    private FloatingText GetFloatingText() {
        FloatingText txt = floatingTexts.Find(t => !t.active);

        if (txt == null){
            txt = new FloatingText();
            txt.go = Instantiate(textPrefab);
            txt.go.transform.SetParent(textContainer.transform);

            txt.txt = txt.go.GetComponent<Text>();
            floatingTexts.Add(txt);


        }

        return txt;

    }



}

those are (above) the "floating text manager script"
```

[My hierarchy and project. "FloatingText" game object occur at under the "FLoatingTextManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Niqa.png)

The codes at the below are chest's code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chest : Collectable // inherited everything from "collidable. 
                                //including mono behaviour.
{

    public Sprite emptyChest;
    public int pesosAmount;

    protected override void OnCollect() {
        
        if (!collected) {
            collected = true;
            pesosAmount = Random.Range(5, 10);
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = emptyChest;
            GameManager.instance.ShowText("+" + pesosAmount + " pesos!", 45, Color.yellow, gameObject.transform.position, Vector3.up * 0, 10);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the scale of the item it’s a child of?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by adding a new "scale" variable to my floating text.